# DocuSign API - I want API for Reports

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Open API'S to generate a report.  Can anyone suggest which API I should use, if any?

I have tried to execute the API from DocuSign but a report API is not available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign does not have an API that allows you to access the web console's Reporting function.

Depending on what you're looking for, you can pull data from the [Envelopes API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes).

DocuSign is developing a Data Feed API that will allow much more in-depth access to information. Data Feed is currently in limited, early access - I would recommend reaching out to your Account Manager or the Sales team if that is of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Tirnuagari, these APIs are not yet public, but we hope to make them public soon. I can't promise an exact time frame, but I'll update this thread when I hear something from the team working on this. Thanks for your patience!